# How to avoid copying the bytes in Dart when deserializing an image from a Flatbuffer?

Tags: flutter, dart, deserialization, flatbuffers, uint8list

**Summary:**

When deserializing a simple flatbuffer containing an image (stored as `[ubyte]`), the generated Dart code returns a `List<int>` that is not a `Uint8List`. Therefore can't be cast to `Uint8List`, and when creating the Image, the bytes must be copied instead, using `Uint8List.fromList()`.

While this does allow me to create the Image from a flatbuffer, the main reason I was using Flatbuffers in the first place was to avoid copying the bytes after loading the buffer. It means that it's better to avoid putting images in a flatbuffer, and instead to just load the image files individually, because that avoids the extra copy. I know, alternatively, that I can try Cap'n Proto or SBE, but I find it surprising that Flatbuffers has this issue, and suspect that perhaps I'm missing a key part.

**Details:**

For clarity, this example uses a minimal Flatbuffer schema. Eventually I want a downloadable resource bundle containing several other fields and many images, perhaps with nested structs or lists of images, but we'll start with this very simple schema containing just a string and one image:

**`fbuf_image.fbs`:**

```
table FbufImage {
  name: string;
  image1: [ubyte]; 
}
root_type FbufImage;
```

After running `flatc --dart fbuf_image.fbs`, the generated Dart code contains a class called `FbufImage` which looks like this:

**The top part of `fbuf_image_generated.dart`:**

```dart
class FbufImage {
  FbufImage._(this._bc, this._bcOffset);
  factory FbufImage(List<int> bytes) {
    final rootRef = fb.BufferContext.fromBytes(bytes);
    return reader.read(rootRef, 0);
  }

  static const fb.Reader<FbufImage> reader = _FbufImageReader();

  final fb.BufferContext _bc;
  final int _bcOffset;

  String? get name => const fb.StringReader().vTableGetNullable(_bc, _bcOffset, 4);
  List<int>? get image1 => const fb.Uint8ListReader().vTableGetNullable(_bc, _bcOffset, 6);

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'FbufImage{name: ${name}, image1: ${image1}}';
  }
}
[...]
```

As you can see, the `get image1` computed property getter returns a `List<int>?`.

This getter is used by the flutter app to get the bytes which are passed to the `Image.memory()` constructor. In the excerpt below, the flatbuffer is loaded from the assets rootBundle, then the image bytes are retrieved using `buffer.image1`:

**In the Flutter app:**

```dart
  final assetBytes = await rootBundle.load("fbuf/${name}.fbuf");
  final Uint8List buffer = assetBytes.buffer.asUint8List();
  if (buffer.length > 0) {
    final bundle = FbufImage(buffer);
    final name = bundle.name ?? "";
    if (bundle.image1 != null) {
      final bytes = bundle.image1 ?? [];
      if (bytes is Uint8List) {
        print("${name}.image1 is already a Uint8List, len=${bytes.length}");
        return Image.memory(bytes as Uint8List);
      }
      print("${name}.image1 is being copied, len=${bytes.length}");
      return Image.memory(Uint8List.fromList(bytes));
    }
  }
```

My app does create the Image but it ALWAYS prints `bundle1.image1 is being copied, len=226933`
IOW, it always does `Uint8List.fromList(bytes)` which copies the bytes.

If I rewrite the code to ignore the `if (bytes is Uint8List)` and try to coerce the cast (i.e. `Image.memory(bytes as Uint8List)`), then I get this runtime exception:
`Expected a value of type 'Uint8List', but got one of type '_FbUint8List'`

Contrast this to the alternative of downloading individual image files which can be loaded and converted to Image objects without the copy:

```dart
  final Directory docDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final File file = File('${docDir.path}/${relPath}/${fname}');
  final Uint8List buffer = await file.readAsBytes();
  if (buffer.length > 0) {
    return Image.memory(buffer);
  }
```

**Q: So how do you avoid copying those image bytes using Flatbuffers?**

Ultimately I'd like to have multiple images bundled in a Flatbuffer and be able to use `Image.memory()` create those images without copying.

Thanks!

[Edit: fixed a mistake in the Flutter deserialization code]

Comment: Forgot to mention, using the latest versions of Flatbuffers and Flutter: (flatc 23.5.26, flat_buffers package Flatbuffers for Dart 23.5.26, Dart SDK 3.2.3, Flutter 3.16.3, macOS Ventura 13.6.1)

Comment: If there's information that you forgot to include in your question, you can just edit your question.  I'd suggest filing an issue, but I see that [you already filed one](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers/issues/8183).